# How to avoid overuse of **kwargs in situation when passing function that takes differing arguments to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

I have a function like so:

```
def outer_function(input1, input2, func):
    a = ....[calculations that depend on input1 and input2]....
    b = ....[calculations that depend on input1 and input2]....
    c = ....[calculations that depend on input1 and input2]....
    d = func(a=a, b=b, c=c)

    return d
```

where I can pass either `func1` or `func2` into the outer_function as the argument `func`. The problem is that `func1` actually only depends on `a` and `b`, and so can be written like

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a')
    b = kwargs.get('b')
    
    return something_with_a_and_b
```

Meanwhile, func2 depends on all 3 values, like so:

```
def func2(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a')
    b = kwargs.get('b')
    c = kwargs.get('c')
    return something_with_a_and_b_and_c
```

This works, but I don't like it because it requires me to pass a lot of stuff (in my actual case) as arguments to `func` within `outer_function` that aren't always used by the actual routine, and so it obscures what my routines actually depend upon (and instead you have to look at what values I'm accessing from **kwargs. Is there a better way to handle this type of situation? I have a cleaner implementation as a class, but I need a functional approach in this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to habdle this is make decorators to handle custom composition of functions. There is not a unique solution since it depdens on the order of composition. Here an example

```
def a(i1, i2): return [i1**1 for i1 in range(i2)]
def b(i1, i2): return [i1**2 for i1 in range(i2)]
def c(i1, i2): return [i1**3 for i1 in range(i2)]

def power_of_2(data: list):
    return [i+2 for i in data]
    
def composer(input1, input2):
    def wrapper(*funcs):  # funcs are a, b, c, ...
        def wrapper2(func): # f is the final function
            return func(sum([f(input1, input2) for f in funcs], [])) # sum flat the list
        return wrapper2
    return wrapper

test1 = composer(3, 4)(a, b)(power_of_2)
print(test1)
test2 = composer(3, 4)(a, b, c)(power_of_2)
print(test2)
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 11]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 11, 2, 3, 10, 29]
```